# How to get the gcc version of .so file on OSX 10.11.6

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, binary

On mac, Enter "gcc -v" in Terminal to get the gcc version as below.

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

How to get the gcc version used to generate the .so file? For example, I want to get the gcc version from a .so file on Mac.

Comment: There's nothing in the `.so` file that marks which version of gcc generated it.